# How to fetch the UIDs using golang imap?

Tags: go

I'm developing an email client using Go [Imap](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap) package. In order to sync the data I need unique identifiers so I'm trying for an hour to find how to set the inbox to return UIDs instead of sequence numbers. Any idea how ? I've tried blindly some commands such  `set, err := imap.NewSeqSet("UID set")` with no positive result. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work... now I need to find how to get the & decode the body:/

```
cmd, err = c.UIDFetch(set, "RFC822.HEADER")
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    return
}

// Process responses while the command is running
fmt.Println("\nMost recent messages:")
for cmd.InProgress() {
    // Wait for the next response (no timeout)
    c.Recv(-1)
    var m Msg
    // Process command data
    for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
        header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.HEADER"])
        UID := imap.AsNumber((rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"]))
```